# Finding the limit of a first order recurrence relation with variable coefficients (usual tricks don't work)

Tags: real-analysis, limits, convergence-divergence, recurrence-relations

I'm stuck in the following recurrence sequence:

Suppose that $a_n$ and $b_n$ are sequences such that $a_n \le b_n$ and $a_n , b_n \sim  cn^2$, where $\sim$ stands for $\frac{a_n}{n^2} \to 1$ as $n \to \infty$, and $c$ is a positive constant. Define a new sequence $S_n$ given by:
$$ S_3 = \frac{2 a_3}{b_3 b_2}, \qquad S_{n}=\frac{a_n}{b_n}\left(\frac{n-1}{b_{n-1}}+S_{n-1}\right), \quad \text{for } n \ge 4 $$.

Assume that $S_n$ is bounded and increasing. Also, suppose that

$$ \prod_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{a_n}{b_n} \to 0.$$

${\textbf{Question:}}$ Is there a way to give a closed form of its limit?

The usual trick to find the fixed point of certain function doesn't work here, because the sequence $a_n/b_n$ converges to $1$. Proceeding in this way, we get the obvious relation

$$ S = S, $$
where $S$ denotes the limit of $S_n$. Notice also that is not hard to find an explicit formula for $S_n$:

$$ S_n = p_n\left(\sum_{j=3}^n\frac{j-1}{p_{j-1}b_{j-1}}\right), $$

where $p_n =\prod_{i=2}^{n}\frac{a_i}{b_i}$. As an example, consider the sequences

$$a_n = \binom{n}{2}, \qquad b_n = a_n+\frac{n}{3}+1. $$

Using some properties of Gamma function we get that $p_n \to 0$ as $n\to \infty$. The sequence $S_n$ is bounded by $3$, and increasing.

My guess is that the limit of $S_n$ is $3$, but I can't prove it. The question arises because I'm trying to figure out a formula for the limit of this kind of sequences, replacing $1/3$ with $0<\lambda<\frac{1}{2}$.

My guess is the same: the limit is $\frac{1}{\lambda}$. I know that making programs is not a proof, but I made one to see if my guesses are correct, and seems they are.

A good reference is a nice starting point. Thanks!!!

Comment: Note that the assumption that $S_n$ is bounded is not guaranteed—take for example $a_n=b_n=n^2$. Increasing is also not guaranteed although examples are a bit less natural.

Comment: I know you said that $S_n$ is bounded and increasing, but I observe that if $a_n = b_n = n^2$, then $S_n$ increases without bound, whereas if $a_3 = 9$, $a_n = n^2-n$ where $n \geq 4$, and $b_n = n^2$, then $S_n = 1$ for all $n \geq 1$. That suggests to me that you cannot give a limit for $\{S_n\}$. (Only a plausibility argument, I admit, but I'm dubious about the existence of a universal limit.)

Comment: @BrianTung Your observation is right. I forgot an interesting assumption, and it is that the infinite product of $a_n/b_n$ diverges to zero.  This can be done using, for example $a_n = \binom{n}{2}$ and $b_n = a_n + \lambda n +1$, where $\lambda$ is a positive constant smaller than $1/2$. (I should relax the condition $a_n \sim n^2$) to $a_n \sim c n^2$ in the question, my mistake)

Comment: Ahh. I think you had better put that in the question! :-) ETA: "diverges to zero" or "converges to zero"?

Comment: @BrianTung I found in diverse sources that the usual term for an infinite product going to zero is "diverges to zero". It has to do with certain duality between series and products.

Comment: @GregMartin Yeah, you're right. See the edit I made. I forgot an extra assumption.

Comment: @UrielHerrera: Interesting!

Answer (score 1):

if $a_n =  n^2 - n $   and $b_n = n^2 +n $   the limit is $\frac{1}{2}$.
Since $s_n = \frac{n^2-n-4}{2n^2 + 2n}  $

Answer (score 0):

if $a_n =  n^2 - n $   and $b_n = n^2  $   the limit is $1$.
Since $s_n = \frac{2n-5}{2n}  $

Comment: Hi. Yeah, it is a good example where the limit can be computed. I added an example where the computations are less obvious, (or maybe I haven't seen the trick yet)